# Error on System.MethodAccessException in 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.LoggerProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use visual studio to create the new web project which is MVC in .net Framework 4.8 under .net core 2.2.

When I use nuget to get the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
and start to run (debug), I got the below exception

```
System.MethodAccessException: 'Attempt by method 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.LoggerProviderConfigurationFactory.GetConfiguration(System.Type)' 
to access method 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ProviderAliasUtilities.GetAlias(System.Type)' failed.'
```

My Project properties is only this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy" Version="2.2.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="4.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Can you help to solve this problem ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was downloading the  Microsoft.Extensions packages and updating the versions so it can be equivalents. 
here were the main answer and the discussions:

> I suspect the issue is due to mismatched package versions. You will
>   certainly need to update all EntityFrameworkCore packages to the same
>   version. I expect you will also need to pull in the latest 3.1
>   versions of Microsoft.Extensions packages, since the EF packages
>   depend on the 3.1 versions of these packages.

[discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18834)

Comment: Hi , I try to add 
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.1.0" />

in my project, but it still have problem :(
Any advise ?

Comment: I do it by nuget solution